# r conditional colors on character variables

Tags: r, colors, gt

I am new to R and found this helper for designing custom fills, which is great, except I am trying to add colors on character variables:
https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cell_fill.html

Here is a test script to apply blue color to the cell `"Arctic"`:

```
# test data
oceans_names <- c("Arctic", "Atlantic", "Indian", "Pacific", "Southern")
avg_depth <- c(1.2, 3.65, 3.74, 3.97, 3.27)
oceans_names <- c("Arctic", "Atlantic", "Indian", "Pacific", "Southern")
highest_depth <- c(18, 30, 24, 36, 28)
oceans_highest_depth <- data.frame(oceans_names, highest_depth)

# set color for 'Arctic'
temp <-select(oceans_highest_depth,  oceans_names, highest_depth)            
)
temp %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "cadetblue2"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = chr,
      rows = chr = "Arctic"
    ))
```

The script returns this message:

```
Error in stop_if_not_gt(data = data) : 
  argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

Any ideas about how to solve this?

I tried `'Arctic'` instead of `"Arctic"` and `character` instead of `chr`.

Answer (score 2):

While you could pass `tidyselect` helpers to the `columns` and `rows` argument, e.g. `where(is.character))` to select `character` columns, for just one column you could pass the column name and more importantly you have to use the column name for your condition:

```
library(gt)

temp %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "cadetblue2"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = oceans_names,
      rows = oceans_names == "Arctic"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @stefan! It seems to work - much appreciated! If I wish to also color "Arctic" in more variables, based on the same rule, how would I do that? I tried writing columns = c(oceans_names, highest_depth) but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Hm. Just using `columns = c(oceans_names, highest_depth)` should color the rows where `oceans_names == "Arctic"` in blue. At least it does when I do it.

Comment: I will try again, thank you for the extra comment!